# Is there a way in Haskell to query thread state using ThreadID after a forkIO?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency, ghc

What I am looking for is a simple function of type:

```
alive :: ThreadID -> IO Bool
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not possible with the standard `base` libraries as far as I know, but you can use the GHC specific API to get a thread's status:

```
import GHC.Conc

alive :: ThreadID -> IO Bool
alive = fmap (== ThreadRunning) . threadStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

Different definition extending on dflemstr's answer to also account for when the thread is blocked. I think it also counts as alive, as pretty soon it's executing code again, once the reason for why it's blocked is taken care of (e.g. an `MVar` is written to, an `STM` transaction on `retry` completes, etc.):

```
import GHC.Conc
import Control.Monad

isThreadStatusBlocked :: ThreadStatus -> Bool
isThreadStatusBlocked (ThreadBlocked _) = True
isThreadStatusBlocked _ = False

isAlive :: ThreadId -> IO Bool
isAlive = fmap (liftM2 (||) (ThreadRunning ==) isThreadStatusBlocked) . threadStatus
```